# iText7 OfficeConverter with Indic languages

Tags: pdf, itext7

I am trying to convert a document(.docx) using iText (trial mode) which contains the text in the TAMIL and KANNADA languages. When PDF is prepared, the output is boxes and language characters are not printed.
What could be the reason for the same?
I am using basic sample from https://itextpdf.com/products/convert-ms-office-to-pdf-pdfoffice

I was also expecting that it will work for ODT format but it FAILS.

```
private static void convert(File in, File out) throws IOException {
        OfficeConverter.convertOfficeDocumentToPdf(in, out, new OfficeDocumentConverterProperties()
                .setPageRange(new OfficePageRange().addPageSequence(1, 8)));
    }
```

## **Input**

[image]

## **Output**

[image]

Comment: Hello @K J , I have trial license. Should it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The problem was that font was not embedded with-in the docx file. [Here is the way to embed the font in document file itself](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/benefits-of-embedding-custom-fonts-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc)